# problem while adding textfield text to NSMutablestring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, nsmutablestring

i need to add textfield text to NSMutable string when end of the textfield end.

for that i use the code

```
- (IBAction)my_textfield_editing {
    if ([my_textfield.text length]!=0) {
        [my_string appendString:my_textfield.text];
        NSLog(@"mystring %@",my_string);
    }
}
```

give this to textfield EditingDidEnd.

but i got some problem here.

for first editing it adds string as string1.

for second editing it adds string as string1string1,string2.

for third editing it adds string as string1string1,string2string1,string2,string3

i think it repeats with previous string.

i am trying placing my_string = NULL before adding it

if i use it always shows null.

how can i resolve it.

can any one help me.

Thank u in advance.

---

Comment: post more context. this code doesn't make much sense. What is my_sms_string? What is my_string. And what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Your use of `appendString:` method here makes no sense. I guess you have to directly use the result string (ie., `my_string`).

Comment: sorry for that,i edit my question

Comment: @MaheshBabu: Did my answer help you? Why you are appending the string?

Comment: yes simon Thank you for your help,this works for me as i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appendString:` method won't work if you assign `Null` to a `NSMutableString'`. In order to make it work, you have to initialize it with some default string. In your case an empty string (ie., `@""`). For example, you have to initialize the mutable string like the following.

```
my_sms_string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
```